# Suitable poi version for HWPF Document and HSSFWorkbook

Tags: apache-poi

Which poi version suitable for word library HWPFDocument and xls library HSSFWorkbook ?

I have tried poi-scratchpad-3.9.jar for HWPFDocument and poi-ooxml-3.6 for HSSFWorkbook, But i always have error when build my app.

Comment: Use the latest stable version. If you "always have error when build your app" then you do something wrong. What? Well that depends on your code and the error which is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

As [helpfully explained in the Apache POI FAQ](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N1019C) (who'd have thought!), you *must* have the POI jars from the same version. Mixing 3.6 and 3.9 jars won't work.

If you really must use old versions of Apache POI for some reason, then ensure that all of your jars (POI, POI-Scratchpad, POI-OOXML etc, based on the [components you are using](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components)) are from the same release

Otherwise, head to the [Apache POI download page](http://poi.apache.org/download.html), grab the latest release, add the [jars you need to your classpath as explained in the components page](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components), ensure you don't have any old jars there, and you'll be all set